# How to plot circles every 20 pixels between two randomly generated points in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

The homework question I'm working on is the following:

> "Draw two randomly placed radius 10 circles on the screen then draw radius 2 circles every twenty pixels from the center of one to the center of the other."

I'm having no trouble randomly generating the two radius 10 circles, but I have no idea how to plot the radius 2 circles between them.

I've tried briefly to plot a line between them, and if there's a way to plot my points along that line, I could definitely do that. I've looked up similar issues and a lot of them mention [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) but I doubt that is the answer as it seems very advanced.

Here is the code I have so far for the problem:

```py
import pygame
from random import randint

linecolour = 0,0,0
bgcolour = 255, 255, 255
width = 600
height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
running = 1

x = []
y = []

for i in range (2):
    x.append(randint(0,600))
    y.append(randint(0,600))


done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # or other types of events
            done = True

    screen.fill(bgcolour)

    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,linecolour,(i,j),10)

        pygame.draw.circle(screen,linecolour,(i,j),2)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: draw `x1+20`, next draw `x1+40`, next `x1+60`, etc. til you get x2. Or use `for x in range(x1, x2, 20):`

Comment: But wouldn't that just affect the x-coordinates? If the y coordinates were different (which they probably will be) then it won't be a line of circles connecting them.

Comment: @furas but is it 20 pixels in the x-direction or 20 total moved between x and y. I thought it was the second case from the post

Comment: "draw radius 2 circles every twenty pixels from the center of one to the center of the other". I assumed it to mean draw a circle every twenty pixels from one point to the other (not necessarily 20 total between the two.) So it would look like a straight line of circles between the two points, each separated by twenty pixels. I think.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the direction vector from 1 point to the other:

```py
dir = x[1]-x[0], y[1]-y[0]
```

Calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the points. Note you've to `import math`:

```py
dist = math.sqrt(dir[0]*dir[0] + dir[1]*dir[1])
```

or as pointed out in the answer of **@MadPhysicist**

```
dist = math.hypot(*dir)
```

the number of points to be drawn is `int(dist) // 20`. Calculate the points on the line in a loop:

```py
for i in range(int(dist) // 20):
    px = int(x[0] + dir[0] * i*20/dist)
    py = int(y[0] + dir[1] * i*20/dist)
```

The code to draw the small points may look like this:

[image]

```py
done = False
while not done:

    # [...]

    dir = x[1]-x[0], y[1]-y[0]
    dist = math.hypot(*dir)
    for i in range(1, int(dist) // 20 + 1):
        pt = int(x[0] + dir[0] * i*20/dist), int(y[0] + dir[1] *i*20/dist)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, linecolour, pt, 2)
```

Comment: `math.sqrt(dir[0]*dir[0] + dir[1]*dir[1])` is `math.hypot(dir[0], dir[1])`

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. When I print the points, however, there is a large gap between the last circle and the centre of the radius 10 circle (almost like one is missing.) Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @SarahUnan `for i in range(1, int(dist) // 20 + 1):`. But note the distance between the points is not exactly divisible by 20. The last gap is not exactly 20

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple problem if you look at it the right way. I would recommend looking at it in terms of polar coordinates. If you have two circles centered at `(x[0], y[0])` and `(x[1], y[1])`, the slope of the line between them is `(y[1] - y[0]) / (x[1] - x[0])`, but you can also look at the *angle* of the line:

```
phi = math.atan2(y[0] - y[1], x[0] - x[1])
```

The distance from one center to the other is given by

```
r = math.hypot(y[0] - y[1], x[0] - x[1])
```

Now you can easily step along the line from `(x[0], y[0])` at an angle of `phi` in steps of 20 until your distance exceeds `r`. The x-coorindate of the i-th step will be

```
i * 20 * math.cos(phi)
```

Similarly the y-coordinate will be

```
i * 20 * math.sin(phi)
```

You can calculate the total number of steps as `r // 20`. Also, `math.sin(math.atan2(y, x))` simplifies to `y / math.hypot(y, x)` and the similar cosine simplifies to `x / math.hypot(y, x)`. So all in all, you get

```
sep = 20
dx = x[1] - x[0]
dy = y[1] - y[0]
r = math.hypot(dy, dx)
n = int(r // sep)
x_step = sep * dx / r
y_step = sep * dy / r
coords = [(x[0] + i * x_step, y[0] + i * y_step) for i in range(n)]
```

If you need integer coordinates:

```
coords = [(x[0] + int(i * x_step), y[0] + int(i * y_step)) for i in range(n)]
```

To plot:

```
for coord in [(x[0] + int(i * x_step), y[0] + int(i * y_step)) for i in range(n)]:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, linecolour, coord, 2)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. results in `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`, from the `range(n)` bit. `coords` should also be integer values! Even when I get it to run, the circles do not connect to each other...

Comment: @Reedinationer. Do you get it to run by doing `range(int(n))`?

Comment: @Reedinationer. I fixed a typo

Comment: With your most recent answer the line goes the opposite way it should. (perhaps because `pygame.display.flip()`, and you still need `int()` coordinates or it will error

Comment: @Reedinationer. Fixed last typo, sorry. Had dx and dy flipped. Also, added version for integer coordinates. `flip` has nothing to do with it since the computations are done in an abstract coordinate system.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. The inner circles should be radius 2 OP said though, not 10.

Comment: @Reedinationer. Thanks for catching my lazy attempts :)